# Very large directory walk hangs without error on OS X 10.9

Tags: python

Writing a little app in system Python (ie. 2.7.1) to get control of my file system. For now it just walks all the volumes and directories of my system and then should be creating a text file with certain formatted data about every file that I'll use later.

The following function doesn't throw an error (well, not within the ~10 minutes I let it hang) but consistently stops at the same file.

When the log file reaches about ~12.8MB, it just stops. Don't even know where to begin! Ideas?

```
   # this function gets used in the function below
    def is_subpath(path, of_paths):
            if isinstance(of_paths, basestring): of_paths = [of_paths]
            abs_of_paths = [os.path.abspath(of_path) for of_path in of_paths]
            return any(os.path.abspath(path).startswith(subpath) for subpath in abs_of_paths)

    # this is the method that hangs; it's part of an essentially empty class at the moment
    def build_master_file_list(self, path):
            self.log.write("***Building master file list...\n")
            last_flush = 1
            for root, directories, files in os.walk(path):
                files = [f for f in files if not f[0] == '.']
                for filename in files:
                    if self.files > last_flush * 1000:
                        self.log.close()
                        self.mfl.close()
                        self.log = open(self.log_path, "a")
                        self.mfl = open(self.mfl_path, "a")
                        time.sleep(0.1)
                        last_flush += 1
                    filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
                    if not is_subpath(filepath, self.no_crawl_list):
                        self.files += 1
                        self.mfl.write(filepath + "\n")
                        self.log.write("Added '{0}' to master_file_list. \n".format(filename))
            self.mfl.close()  # self.mfl is just a text file, ie. "master file list"
```

**UPDATE:** In fact it seems to be hanging on the last file. I've modified the function to reflect some of the comments below, and the code above now reflects this.

There are 4 Volumes being walked. One of them is 3TB, one is a 400GB SSD and the other is a 150GB. The 150GB disk is the last to be processed, and it's the last file on this disk that marks (I won't claim causes) the hang.

Comment: unrelated but you can check `if not is_subpath(filepath, self.no_crawl_list):`  and remove the pass and else

Comment: Also why are you using `directories[:] = [d for d in directories if not d[0] == '.']`?

Comment: you could try flushing the file handle after each write(or every 1000 writes) and maybe a brief sleep or something.... what you think is the last file might not actually be the last file

Comment: @PadraicCunningham For the current iteration of the project I'm not working with hidden files, it's just a fast way to clean those files out of the directory list.

Comment: @JoranBeasley trying that now....

Comment: I just meant once you directories = ... that will reassign the name directories to the new list. Also I don't see you use directories anywhere after so you just seem to be adding overhead for no reason.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham lol you're right, thanks for that, there was a previous version of this wherein I did use the directories list. Deleted!

Comment: How big is the file system?  Are you printing out the filenames so you can actually see where you are?

Comment: So the loop we see literally hangs on the last file? You do also call close on the file object? You should also really use a `with` block to handle the opening and closing.

Comment: What happens if you only walk the last disk?

Comment: I would also open the files outside the loop once using a with statement. If you want to force the write you could  call`os.fsync(file_object)`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Further good advice, thanks. I ran the loop on just the final volume as per your suggestion.. there *was* an error getting thrown at the beginning of the next function, but it wasn't printing to my console. That's strange, though, since 80% of the files are on that last disk (19.4MB of 25.9MB worth of output to the Master File List).

Comment: Where were you running the code from? Also what was the error?

Comment: The error was really trivial, AttributeError from trying to call `.join()` on a string. And I'm executing the code from terminal, ie. `python file_system_scan.py /Volumes/150gbdisk`

Comment: It is a bit  weird that the traceback did not propagate to the terminal. Does the code complete catching the error?